# How to manage multi language in server side code?

Tags: asp.net

I've an ASP.NET web application. I've some message 'string' managed in server side code. Can anyone give me the best practice example codes for managing multi language ? 
For example:

```
if Language ="en" then

   labelMessage.label ="my message" 

else if language="es" then

   labelMessage.label = "esto es un .."

end if
```

Comment: search for internationalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is to use Resources and Culture to switch the context of the application, you have the information based on .Net 2.0 but it is still the same procedure and code:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx

Comment: Thanks, ok... but how about "server-side" code .. how to call a resource label ?